# nested loop, hash and merge which one is best to choose?

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-execution-plan

Which one a developer should choose nested loop, hash or merge ?

Which is efficient in which way?

Thanks

Comment: [Difference between Hash, Merge and Loop join?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/937/difference-between-hash-merge-and-loop-join)

Comment: I don't think there is the "best" one. They are all good depending on situation and cardinality.

Comment: which one good for which situation?